# How to open modal after i choose image?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

What I want is when user choose image to open modal where it will have option to crop his image. This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/2511/) where he can crop image but at view.

```
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  img id="blah" class="crop" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
  <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
  <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
  <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching your fiddle you should know that you were close enough. Just do the following.

```
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
     console.log(this);
     readURL(this);
     $("#yourModal").modal('show);
});
```

Comment: Im trying r code but modal wont open..i tried with button and it works but like this not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $("#yourModal").show(); use $('#yourModal').modal('show');

Use the following code:

```
      $('#imgInp').change(function(){

        $('#yourModal').modal('show');

      });
```

This will definitely work for you.